# My discord bot have a error "Traceback (most recent call last):"

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have error with my discord bot 
My discord bot error look like this: I run in iTerm2 and error looks like this
And picture is my code

```
    [The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 14, in <module>
    client.run('BOT TOKEN')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 640, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 621, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 584, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 442, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 261, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 165, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 480, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 523, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 858, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1004, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 980, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 938, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discordapp.com:443 ssl:True \[SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '\[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED\] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')\]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you just leaked your bot token, but don't worry discord should have generated a new token so go grab that. If that doesn't already fix it, you could show us the code. And next time remove your bot token before you post here.

Comment: I know yesterday they bombed my server so I regenerated new token.

Comment: And now you uploaded that one here? Discord regenerated a new token for you. Go take the new token and try with that. If doesn't work you should upload your code (next time without the token).